# Validate causes heavy lagg

Tags: c#

I'm making a sort of shooting game in c#.
I created a aim and a target using c# graphics.
This forced me to use `Invalidate();` however this caused heavy flickering and laggs.
I fixed the flickering using `DoubleBuffered = true;` but i still have very heavy laggs when running the programm.

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        minTavla1 = new Mål(ClientSize.Width / 2, ClientSize.Height / 2, 50);
        sikte = new Sikte(ClientSize.Width / 3, ClientSize.Height / 3, 20);
        skott = new skott(ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height / 3, 5);
        minTavla1.X = 150;
        minTavla1.Y = 150;
        timer1.Start();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        //minTavla2 = new Mål(50, 50, 50);
        //minTavla3 = new Mål(150, 200, 50);


    }
    int i = 0;
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        if (pictureBox1.Visible == true)
        {
            skott.X = e.X;
            skott.Y = e.Y;
        }
        Skott.Play();
        if (pictureBox1.Visible == false)
        {
            Reload.Play();
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            timer3.Start();
        }
        if (pictureBox2.Visible == false)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        }
        if (pictureBox3.Visible == false)
        {
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        }
        if (pictureBox4.Visible == false)
        {
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
        }
        if (pictureBox5.Visible == false)
        {
            pictureBox4.Visible = false;
        }
        pictureBox5.Visible = false;
        if (skott.X > minTavla1.X - 50 && skott.Y < minTavla1.Y + 50)
        {
            if (skott.X < minTavla1.X + 50 && skott.Y > minTavla1.Y - 50)
            {
                i += 5;
                label1.Text = i.ToString();
                timer2.Start();
            }
            if (skott.X > minTavla1.X - 10 && skott.Y < minTavla1.Y + 10)
            {
                if (skott.X < minTavla1.X + 10 && skott.Y > minTavla1.Y - 10)
                {
                    i += 5;
                    label1.Text = i.ToString();
                    timer4.Start();
                }

            }
        }
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        minTavla1.Rita(e.Graphics);
        sikte.Ritasikte(e.Graphics);
        skott.ritaskott(e.Graphics);

        //minTavla2.Rita(e.Graphics);
        //minTavla3.Rita(e.Graphics);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        sikte.X = e.X;
        sikte.Y = e.Y;
    }

    private void pbxMal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("5points");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        minTavla1.X += 5;
        this.Invalidate();

    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer2.Interval > 100)
        {
            minTavla1.X = -200;
        }
    }

    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Increment(+1);

        if (progressBar1.Value == 5)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
            pictureBox3.Visible = true;
            pictureBox4.Visible = true;
            pictureBox5.Visible = true;
            timer3.Stop();
        }

    }

    private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar2.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar2.Increment(+1);
        pictureBox6.Visible = true;

        if (progressBar2.Value == 10)
        {
            pictureBox6.Visible = false;
            progressBar2.Value = 0;
            timer4.Stop();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you doing all of this in one (the UI) thread?

Comment: Have you ran this against a profiling tool to identify potential bottlenecks?

Comment: Winforms is not really a suitable framework for game development.  There won't be a simple fix for this problem.  It's like trying to open a can with a bottle opener.  I would suggest re-thinking your development using something like the XNA framework.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203940.aspx

Comment: Ontopic: XNA is the way for loop driven games. WPF is better for event driven games.
Off-topic: no try-catch blocks? Don't want those exceptions being eaten!

Comment: `Winforms is not really a suitable framework for ...` ... anything I can possibly think of.